# Are there multiple conjugacy classes of order 2 elements in the smooth automorphism group of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology, automorphism-groups, transformation-groups

Consider the group $\text{Aut}\mathbb{R}$ of smooth invertible maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If $f\in\text{Aut}\mathbb{R}$ has order 2 ($f$ is an involution), is $f$ conjugate to $g(x)=-x$?

The answer is "yes" if we replace the word "smooth" with "continuous" or "continuously differentiable", but I do not know how to resolve this in the case of smooth automorphisms.

Comment: This is widely known as (smooth) *diffeomorphism* group. It's true. One way to prove this is to observe that $g$ preserves a Riemannian metric, and then use that every Riemannian manifold that is homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}$ is smoothly isometric to an interval of $\mathbf{R}$. By the existence of an orientation-reversing involution, it has to be smoothly isometric to $\mathbf{R}$ or $]-1,1[$. One easily concludes.